# How can I determined how many times A number is contained into another number in UNSIGNED binary without using the operators <,>,<=,>=?

Tags: state-machine

I have to draw a State Machine where two numbers such as A=20 and B=6 for example are keep getting subtracting like so: 20-6=14-6=8-6=2-6=-4 overflow gets triggered in the ALU therefore the result is 3. Since A and B are inputs received in 2 different cycles how can I check them without using the comparison operator?

I tried to add B instead of subtracting A, but the problem is still when I have to compare the two values.